# How are Top Questions generated, and how can the Stack Overflow landing page be customized to be more useful?

Tags: discussion

Over the last year or so I've gradually noticed a trend - and that trend is the Top Questions page (at least the one I'm seeing) being flooded with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) questions.

Now, I don't work with Android, and while some of the questions may be interesting, the fact that 9/10 of the questions on the 'default' home page for Stack Overflow (i.e. https://stackoverflow.com) are completely irrelevant to me means that Top Questions is essentially pointless for my usage of Stack Overflow.

My question is, how are Top Questions generated with respect to a particular user? Is the list different per user or is it the same for everyone? If it is the same for everyone, what ways can we as users of Stack Overflow customize the landing page to make the first content we see actually be relevant?

Thank you.

Comment: The list I believe is the same for everybody, which is why you can add your favorite tags (mine for example, javascript, nodejs, react, coldfusion, etc) to highlight the questions that pertain to you.

Comment: @SterlingArcher: No, it's not the same. It's based on your use of the site, watched tags, and ignored tags.

Comment: probably based on your predication data: https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data

Comment: Yeah, I rarely get android information on my top questions page, have you been answering a lot of android questions?

Comment: I don't think I've answered a single one. It might have been the review queue, but I've been on and off the failed audit list for that so I'm not sure if that kind of activity factors in much.